# How to find prevent ResourceManager to default back to default Resource file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, embedded-resource, resourcemanager

Ive got some code which works somehow good, with except of one tiny little problem.

I have 3 resource files:

```
- Resource.da.resx (cultureID = 6)
-Resource.en.resx (cultureID = 9)
-Resource.resx - default
```

If browser loads and it would like to have "en" or "en-US" culture, this method works fine. However if i ask for german ("de") culture getResourceSet returns default Resource set, which i would like to prevent, to just find out that this resource set is not available. Can it be done?

```
    public bool doesCultureExist(string cultureName)
    {
            try
            {
                global::System.Resources.ResourceManager rm =
                new global::System.Resources.ResourceManager("Resources.Resource", global::System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
                var cult = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(cultureName);

                ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(cult, true, true);
                if (rs != null)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else { return false; }
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried passing a `false` as the third .GetResourceSet() parameter (tryParents), like:

```
ResourceSet rs = rm.GetResourceSet(cult, true, false);
```

?